# Question about the electric dipole radiation

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, dipole, antennas

I can understand why an oscillating electric dipole emmits electromagnetic rdiation-charges are constantly accelerating. But how come fixed electric dipoles with varing charges also emmit E-M radiation? I know the fundamental physical quantity that describes an electric dipole is the electric dipole moment, p=ql,from this expression, varing charges and varing distance produce the same effect on p. So, I can understand it mathematically,but can not understand physically. Anyone any ideals?

Comment: Short answer: There is acceleration  AND changing charge density. The cuangjng current element just exists in a single point in space

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How a dipole should behave in order to produce an electromagnetic field?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/720536/)

Answer (score 0):

An infinitely small dipole in the form

$$\rho = \vec{P} \cdot \nabla \delta^3(r)$$

Will only have an acceleration/ changing current density/ radiation given:

$$\frac{d^2\vec{P}}{dt^2} ≠ 0$$

The reason is simple:

$$\nabla \cdot \vec{J} = - \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$$

Solving for $\vec{J}$ gives

$\vec{J} = \frac{d\vec{P}}{dt}\delta^3(r)$

Taking the derivative:

$\frac{\partial\vec{J}}{\partial t} = \frac{d^2\vec{P}}{dt^2}\delta^3(r)$

From Jefimenkos equations, the radiation field is completely dependant on $\frac{\partial\vec{J}}{\partial t}$

If $$\frac{d^2\vec{P}}{dt^2} = 0$$ then clearly no radiation is produced.

Your mistake is assuming there is no changing current density for a dipole with a varying dipole moment. It does, aslong as it's dipole moment change is not constant.

It may seem weird for there to be a changing current density at a SINGLE point in space. But there is.

If $\frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial t^2}$ ≠ 0  then $\frac{\partial \vec{J}}{\partial t} ≠ 0$

Answer (score 0):

If there is a changing charge density, then there must be accelerating charges somewhere.  As an example of this, suppose we have two small conducting spheres separated by a distance $l$ and connected by an electrically neutral wire.  Through Methods, we drive current in the wire so that the charge on each sphere is $q(t) = \pm q_0 \sin (\omega t)$, and so the dipole moment is $p(t) = q_0 l \sin (\omega t)$.

Since charge is conserved, the current in the wire must satisfy $I(t) = - dq/dt = - q_0 \omega \cos (\omega t)$.  This implies that the speed of the charges in the wire is constantly changing, and so there are in fact accelerating charges present.

Comment: A moving point charge at a constant speed has a changing charge density function, but zero acceleration. $$\frac{\partial^2 \rho }{\partial t^2} ≠ 0$$  Is needed for acceleration/ radiation

Comment: That last mathematical statement of mine is wrong.

Comment: so, does this mean that the radiation is given off by the accelrating charges in the wire, not by the charged spheres?